# How to squash two selects together when joins don't seem to work

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've got a feeling this is a super basic question but I'm missing something. I have two queries, the first is

```
SELECT 

[User Name]

,sum(datediff(SECOND,[signon time],[Signoff Time])) as [Shift Seconds]
,sum([Signon Duration]) as [Signon]
,sum([Total Logon Duration]) as [logged on seconds]
,sum([Total Activation Duration]) as [active seconds]
,sum([Pre Signoff DND Duration]) as [DND]
,sum([Total Idle Duration]) as [Idle]
,sum([Total Pickup Duration]) as [Pickup]
,sum([Pre Signoff DND Duration]) as [Pre Signoff DND Duration]

From 

[iPR].[dbo].[AgentSignonStatus]

where 

[Signon Time] between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-08'




group by [User Name]
order by [User Name]
```

Which gives this output

[image: Output 1]

and this query

```
SELECT

[agent name]

,sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call') ,1,0)) as [Calls Answered]
,sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),[connected (secs)],NULL)) AS [Total Duration of Answered Calls]

From

 InboundCallsView 

 where 

[Start Time] between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-08'

 group by [Agent Name]

 order by [Agent Name]
```

which gives this output

[image: output 2]

I've tried left joining agent signon to inboundcalls on [user name] = [agent name] right joining and a UNION. I also tried a SELECT within a SELECT but whatever I try seem to multiply one field or another many times over. I'm guessing it's something to do with a many to one situation but I'm basically stuck at this point. All I want to see is
[image: desired output]

but I'm totally missing how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join your queries as derived tables (subqueries) or using [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) like so:

```
with cte as (
  SELECT 
    [User Name]
    ,sum(datediff(SECOND,[signon time],[Signoff Time])) as [Shift Seconds]
    ,sum([Signon Duration]) as [Signon]
    ,sum([Total Logon Duration]) as [logged on seconds]
    ,sum([Total Activation Duration]) as [active seconds]
    ,sum([Pre Signoff DND Duration]) as [DND]
    ,sum([Total Idle Duration]) as [Idle]
    ,sum([Total Pickup Duration]) as [Pickup]
    ,sum([Pre Signoff DND Duration]) as [Pre Signoff DND Duration]
  From [iPR].[dbo].[AgentSignonStatus]
  where [Signon Time] between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-08'
  group by [User Name]
  --order by [User Name]
)
, inbound as (
  SELECT
    [agent name]
    ,sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call') ,1,0)) as [Calls Answered]
    ,sum(iif([Type] in ('Normal operator call'),[connected (secs)],NULL)) 
      AS [Total Duration of Answered Calls]
  From InboundCallsView 
  where [Start Time] between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-08'
  group by [Agent Name]
  --order by [Agent Name]
)
select cte.*
  , inbound.[Calls Answered]
  , inbound.[Total Duration of Answered Calls]
from cte
  inner join inbound
    on cte.[User Name] = inbound.[agent name]
order by cte.[User Name]
```

If you need a different join other than an `inner join` then it should be an easy fix. It looks like you should have a 1:1 match based on using the same `where` clauses.

Comment: I usually just fix it but looks like you was still editing ;)

Comment: This worked great, Thanks! I feel like I was doing something similar to this but getting totally different results I didn't bracket off and name my first select like you did was that the issue?

Comment: @tomdemaine I imagine you were trying to join the two tables before doing aggregation, and that was causing 1 row to match multiple row both ways between the tables and inflating your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that roughly it should follow this mechanism:

```
select isnull(a.username, b.agentname), *
from
(...query 1 sql...) a
full outer join
(...query 2 sql...) b on a.username = b.agentname
```